# Configuring PayPal Auto-Return (Redirect) After Payment

Tags: redirect, paypal, payment-processing

I do not know what happened but before, The redirect after payment was going very well, now is not working anymore.

I have this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mail@name.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<? echo $site->site_brand;?> <? echo $pack->name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<? echo $pack->days;?> Days">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? echo $data->id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo $pack->price;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>/getpremium.php">
<input style="width:110px;border:none;background:none;" type="image" src="_template/images/buynow.png" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" class="premium_hide" /><img alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

I do not understand what could be wrong now. Perhaps Paypal changed something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you stating that the buyer is not being returned, or that the buyer is being returned, but no data is being passed back to your site with the redirect?  Also is the buyer paying with a credit card or PayPal account.  The redirect will not be automatic if the buyer is paying with a credit card and going through the guest checkout.

Comment: when the buyer buy with paypal not working redirect to the site